# <a> tags not clickable in Internet Explorer 7 - why?

Tags: css, hyperlink, internet-explorer-7

I've got myself multiple a tags floating on a page.

They have been styled in a unique way to center an image horizontally inside it, using a span and css. The a tag itself has fixed width and height.

I thought this was basic stuff, and my theme was causing the issue, but I've created a stripped down [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/motocomdigital/Qk9tu/6/) and I'm still getting the same problem when running the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/motocomdigital/Qk9tu/6/) in IE 7.

The a tags are all click-able in every browser apart from IE7, why is this happening?

Can anyone explain? Thanks.

http://jsfiddle.net/motocomdigital/Qk9tu/6/ - Test click-able state in IE7, works fine everywhere else.

Don't worry about IE 6 - I'm not coding for this anymore.

Comment: If you remove `position:absolute` from the `span` tag, does it work?

Comment: it changes it a bit, it seems you can click on the span, but not the img. Because when I remove the absolute position from the span, I lose the center position of the image, which means I can see the img and the span, and in IE7 the span is sort of clickable, you can click it but no cursor pointer appears, and the img is not click-able.. weird

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve what you are trying to do with just CSS, but it requires a slightly different layout in your HTML and some extra CSS.

**JSFiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/8E8um/2/**

**Note**

In `a.home-module` I have added a transparent image. This is because IE7 will not assign an "empty" parameter (due to the negative text-indent) to the top level and would therefore still leave the link unclickable.

Answer (score 3):

On IE, a link element (`<a></a>`) with an empty attribute `href` doesn't display a link-cursor (hand).

Either put a `#` in your `href` attributes or add a `cursor:pointer` on `a.home-module`

Comment: Yeah you are right, but it still doesn't solve my issue of not being able to click the link in IE7. See updated jsFiddle, a tags still not click-able.. and I added URLs in the href - [http://jsfiddle.net/motocomdigital/Qk9tu/6/](http://jsfiddle.net/motocomdigital/Qk9tu/6/)

Answer (score 2):

It's the spans inside the a that cause the trouble...

Comment: hmmmm, this does make sense - divs and javascript it is then

Answer (score 0):

you should assign "#" to href attribute.

Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/Qk9tu/5/

Comment: Hi, I still can't click it in IE7 :-(